# Link servers to RD Licencing server

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, remote-desktop, remote-desktop-services

I have around 20 servers that are running at the moment, they are working on the 120 day RDP grace period.

I have now set up a server to act as the licencing server and connection broker.

All these servers are on the same domain.

I was wondering how I link each server used for remote desktop to my licencing server?

I am using 2012R2 for every server.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Open Server Manager.
2. Navigate to the Remote Desktop Services navigation area.
3. Select the Overview branch.
4. Under the Deployment Overview area, select Edit Deployment Properties from the Tasks menu.
5. Select the RD Licensing page of the displayed dialog.
6. Specify the licensing mode and the license server, then click OK.

Comment: This answered my question perfectly. Unfortunately the hard part was trying to apply SPLA licences that had been bought and paid for by a previous owner of the business but never applied. 18+ hours on the phone to our supplier and Microsoft later I finally learned how to get and apply the licences

Comment: Anybody interested in this check my blog blog dot alech dot net